# __asm using c++ variables (MSVS 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I am trying to add two c long variables (as I am trying to gradually understand assembly) :

```
long add(long _a, long _b){
    __asm{
        mov rax, _a;
        add _b, rax;
    }
    return _b;
}
```

All I get is improper operand type errors. Now I realize I could do

```
return _a + _b;
```

But I am doing this just to understand assembly.

Comment: Are you by chance compiling for 32bit ? `rax` isn't known there. And it should output "operands of different size" in 64bit. Also, no need for `;` at the end.

Comment: infact yes. Any idea how to enable the 64 bit compiler?

Comment: No idea for Visual Studio, but google should help you there. Anyway, use `eax` instead of `rax` and it should work, for both 64 and 32 bit ( I strongly assume ).

Comment: VS does not support [inline assembly for 64bit targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx).